# Registering RabbitMQ Consumer with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to handle request authorization in a microservice based architecture using a message queue (RabbitMQ).

I've got a receiver and sender configured fine as a console application in .NET Core per these [instructions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html). However, when using this in a real world example, my application receiving project isn't collecting messages as a consumer.

I'm assuming I have to register the consumer in the `Startup.cs`, but I can't seem to get this working.

My consumer/responder code:

```
public class RabbitMqHandler 
{
    private readonly IJWTFactory _jwtFactory;

    public RabbitMqHandler(IJWTFactory jWTFactory)
    {
        _jwtFactory = jWTFactory;

    }

    public void Register()
    {
        var mqFactory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

        using (var connection = mqFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening on Rabbit MQ");
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "Authorize", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var jwtToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                    Console.WriteLine("Rceived Message");

                    var validatedToken = _jwtFactory.ValidateTokenSignature(jwtToken);

                    SendResponse(validatedToken);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "Authorize", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Deregister()
    {

    }
```

`Startup.cs` to register the 
    .AddSingleton()

Edit: I've added some additional listening code, this is definitely running on startup, but RabbitMQ is not showing the app as a consumer or a channel:

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtentions
{
    public static RabbitMqHandler Listener { get; set; }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRabbitListener(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        Listener = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RabbitMqHandler>();

        var life = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IApplicationLifetime>();

        life.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);

        //press Ctrl+C to reproduce if your app runs in Kestrel as a console app
        life.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);

        return app;
    }

    private static void OnStarted()
    {
        Listener.Register();
    }

    private static void OnStopping()
    {
        Listener.Deregister();
    }
}
```

To summarise:

- How do I correctly configure a consumer in .NET Core to consume messages?
- Is this just the wrong to expect a Message Queue to manage request/response style communication?
- Should I just be using an API call to authenticate and authorize users?

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? `consumer.Received` never fired?

Comment: @Evk Seems so, in my server I can't see the consumer either. So I'm not even sure if the `channel.basicConsume` is working either.

Comment: Ah I see the problem - you are closing channel and connection right after consuming starts. Remove all usings, move `connection ` and `channel` to fields of `RabbitMqHandler` class and close them in `Unregister`, not in `Register`.

Comment: @Evk Trying that now! Just out of interest, where in my code am I closing the channel? Is it the `BasicConsume` or because of the `using`?

Comment: Well, `using` is designed to dispose things, it calls `Dispose` when you reach the end of using block. `BasicConsume` is not blocking call, so it starts consumption and returns immediately. Right after that end of using blocks is reached for both `channel` and `connection`, disposing them (and disposing them is the same as closing).

Comment: @Evk That's working like a charm now. For some reason, my brain hadn't considered the fact that `using` would be closing the connections despite it being very obvious. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Answer as provided by [@Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk) (in the comments):

> "`using` is designed to dispose things, it calls `Dispose` when you reach the end of the `using` block. `BasicConsume` is not a blocking call, so it starts consumption and returns immediately.
>
> Right after that the end of the `using` blocks is reached for both channel and connection, disposing them (and disposing them is the same as closing)."

I'd like to add the following:
You can quickly try if removing the using brings the desired result very easily. Change the following code line:

```
using (var connection = mqFactory.CreateConnection())
```

to:

```
var connection = mqFactory.CreateConnection();
```

This will instantly do the trick. But be aware it also removes proper disposal - so you need to add that - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1063?view=vs-2019) is an article from Microsoft describing how `IDisposable` is to be implemented correctly.